# BMP Siting Tool gives error at validateDatasets_ST: Error HRESULT E_FAIL returned from call to COM component?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, toolbar

I'm trying to use a toolbar that was developed by the EPA that is BMP Siting Tool. I also have done what was ordered in BMP Siting Tool User Guide, but still failed until now.
When I run BMP Siting Tool and wait for the result, then a dialog box appears

> error at validateDatasets_ST: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Any idea what's causing this? I'm using ArcGIS 10.1. If maybe anyone have a sample file for using on BMP Siting Tool?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Was the toolbar made for ArcGIS 10.1?  Unfortunately for a specialised toolbar such as this you might not have much luck here.  Are you able to contact the developer directly?

Comment: Yeah, this toolbar is developed for ArcGIS 10.1. I've contacted the developer related to this issue and I am still waiting for them to answer my email.

Comment: What are the detailed steps that you are using when you see this error?  With those perhaps another user of this tool may be able to reproduce and debug the cause of the error for you.